"Minimal resolutions" of derived complete modules
Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ be a complete Noetherian local ring. If $M$ is a derived $\mathfrak{m}$-complete $A$-module then there exists a resolution $P_{\bullet} \twoheadrightarrow M$ such that each $P_n$ is the completion of a free $A$-module (take an ordinary free resolution and degreewise complete it). Can $P_{\bullet}$ be chosen so that $\partial P_{n+1} \subseteq \mathfrak{m} P_n$ for all $n$? Equivalently, does any derived $\mathfrak{m}$-complete $M$ admit a surjection $\pi : P \twoheadrightarrow M$ where $P$ is a completed free module and $\ker \pi \subseteq \mathfrak{m} M$? More generally, is every right-bounded derived $\mathfrak{m}$-complete complex quasi-isomorphic to a right-bounded complex $P_{\bullet}$ of completed free modules such that $\partial P_{n+1} \subseteq \mathfrak{m} P_n$?
